# How to wait on an array being filled by another promise

Tags: javascript, promise

d3 is loading a Global array. I want to call that data in another function.

I don't understand promises very well and I can't decipher documentation.

First function called does:

```
d3.tsv( ... ).then(function(data){Loaded_Data[0]=data);}
```

Then a function is called to populate my svg:

```
svg.getElementById("example") = Loaded_Data[0][Loaded_Data[0].length-1]['Example Column']
```

I just can't figure out how to code: "Promise me that there is data in this Array, then do the value assignment"

Please be as explicit and obvious as possible. Thank you.

Comment: `ta);}` braket order is off

Comment: "*Then a function is called*" - where exactly is that function called? You should do it inside the `then` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ES8 feature `async/await`,
Let's imagine that you are executing your logic in a function called `foo`,

```
// If you are using await inside a function it should be declared as async
async function foo(){

// await will make sure to pause the execution till the promise is resolved
Loaded_Data[0]=await d3.tsv( ... );

svg.getElementById("example") = Loaded_Data[0][Loaded_Data[0].length-1]['Example Column'] 

}
```

For more on `async/await`, here is a great article,

https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/

Comment: This doesn't really help. I already have Loaded_Data being filled in the promise of d3.

Comment: I am waiting on two separate promises. One to wait on loading the SVG and another to d3.tsv. I want to combine my two promises with the loaded_data array.

Comment: @HAZRD If you want to wait for both promises you can use ```const results=await Promise.all([promises, promise2])```

Answer (score 1):

If your 2 code snippets are in the same `.js` file then you can likely just do:

```
d3.tsv( ... ).then(function(data){
    Loaded_Data[0]=data;
    svg.getElementById("example") = Loaded_Data[0][Loaded_Data[0].length-1]['Example Column'];
}
```

If this is not the case, then you could use an [Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable), or you could trigger a custom Event that is called from within your `.then`.

```
d3.tsv( ... ).then(function(data){
     Loaded_Data[0]=data;
     var event = new Event('Loaded_Data_HasData');
     window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

and then in your other file / location, listen for that event.

```
elem.addEventListener('Loaded_Data_HasData', function (e) { 
    svg.getElementById("example") = Loaded_Data[0][Loaded_Data[0].length-1]['Example Column']; 
}, false);
```